# Screen Flicker on Loki

Tags: release-loki, display, performance

I try to fix this so many times since I install elementaryOS. And I try [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1435861/comments/5) fix but do not work. Also changed to `UXA` and either.

I have

```
Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

This happens right now writing from Chrome, maybe is just the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this
[solution](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0CtKF2BiskT8/?hl=en)?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 right now, but I'll try this solution and see what happens.

Comment: Not sure, but I think i solved with the Flags "GPU rasterization" on "Force-enabled for all layers"

Comment: it worked for me